# Fix date in MySQL

Tags: mysql, date, format

Here's the syntax:

```
string insert_query = "insert into book_borrow (BookID, MemberID, Date_Borrow, Date_Return) values ('" + BookID + "', '" + MemberID + "', curdate(), dateadd(month,1, getdate()))";
const char* q = insert_query.c_str();
qstate = mysql_query(conn, q);
```

I have error to query execution Problem! 1305

I want to automatically add return date after current date but I can't get it.

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: *`dateadd(month,1, getdate())`* Looks like SQL Server (MS SQL) code, not MySQL...

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL, it will be DATE_ADD() not dateadd(), document can be found [here](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-date_add-function.php).

Also do not trust user input like BookID and MemberID to prevent SQL injection. Try using prepared statements.

Try the below SQL

```
string insert_query = "insert into book_borrow (BookID, MemberID, Date_Borrow, Date_Return) 
values ('" + BookID + "', '" + MemberID + "', CURDATE(), DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH))";
```

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)